# Spring data - MongoDB - case insensitive

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I use this query and I will make the search case insensitive:

```
@Query("{ $or: [ { 'name' : { $regex: ?0 }, 'number' : { $regex: ?1 } } ] }")
```

Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use options to force case insensitivity: `$options: 'i'`

```
@Query("{ $or: [ { 'name' : { $regex: ?0 }, 'number' : { $regex: ?1 } } ], { $options: 'i' } }")
```

Comment: For some reasons it does not seach case insensitive

Comment: What are the exact regex pattern you are going to search for name and number ?

Comment: I found out that this works for me: @Query("{ '$or': [{ 'name': { $regex: ?0, '$options': 'i' } }, { 'number': { '$regex': ?0, '$options': 'i' } }